# Why the following code is pulling only the ID name of first image?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 4 images with below 4 id names:

"ObiWan", "Luke", "Sidious", "Maul";

All of them have 1 class name: "images".

But with the below code, no matter which image I press, it only shows "ObiWan" as ID for all 4 of those images in the Console Log.

```
select = $(".image").one("click", function() {


console.log(select.attr('id'));

if (select.attr("id")==="ObiWan"){
    $("#player").append($("#ObiWan"));
    $("#enemies").append($("#Luke"));
    $("#enemies").append($("#Sidious"));
    $("#enemies").append($("#Maul"));
} else if (select.attr("id")==="Luke"){
    $("#player").append($("#Luke"));
    $("#enemies").append($("#ObiWan"));
    $("#enemies").append($("#Sidious"));
    $("#enemies").append($("#Maul"));
} else if (select.attr("id")==="Sidious"){
    $("#player").append($("#Sidious"));
    $("#enemies").append($("#ObiWan"));
    $("#enemies").append($("#Luke"));
    $("#enemies").append($("#Maul"));
} else if (select.attr("id")==="Maul"){
    $("#player").append($("#Maul"));
    $("#enemies").append($("#ObiWan"));
    $("#enemies").append($("#Luke"));
    $("#enemies").append($("#Sidious"));
}

});
```

Comment: All of them have class `images` but you select `.image`. Is that a problem? Use `$(this).attr('id')` instead of `select.attr()`

Comment: I used .image to call the class named as images. And $(this) does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
// person array
var person = ["ObiWan", "Luke", "Sidious", "Maul"];

// this is event delegate, if your new img.image attach click event handler.
$(document).on("click", ".image", function($e) {
  var id = $($e.currentTarget).attr("id");
  console.log(id);

  // #player
  $("#player").append($("#"+id));
  person.forEach(function(person) {
    if(id === person) { // #player -> not enemy...!
      return;
    }
    // #enemies
    $("#enemies").append($("#"+person));
  });
});
```

Comment: if you're going to improve the code, then I'd say also change the unscalable `#enemies` append. Use an array to output the enemies instead.

Comment: @A.Lau I agree your opinion.. hahaha.. I'll try it!

Comment: Thank you @seunggabi . This one works like a charm! :)

Comment: Thanks for your opinion as well @A.Lau

Comment: @ShahriarFiroz if this answers your question, remember to click on the tick.

Answer (score 1):

You should replace select with `$(this)` like the following:

```
$(".image").one("click", function (e) {
  var imageID = e.target.id;
  console.log(imageID);
  if (imageID === "ObiWan") {
    $("#player").append($("#ObiWan"));
    $("#enemies").append($("#Luke"));
    $("#enemies").append($("#Sidious"));
    $("#enemies").append($("#Maul"));
  } else if (imageID === "Luke") {
    $("#player").append($("#Luke"));
    $("#enemies").append($("#ObiWan"));
    $("#enemies").append($("#Sidious"));
    $("#enemies").append($("#Maul"));
  } else if (imageID === "Sidious") {
    $("#player").append($("#Sidious"));
    $("#enemies").append($("#ObiWan"));
    $("#enemies").append($("#Luke"));
    $("#enemies").append($("#Maul"));
  } else if (imageID === "Maul") {
    $("#player").append($("#Maul"));
    $("#enemies").append($("#ObiWan"));
    $("#enemies").append($("#Luke"));
    $("#enemies").append($("#Sidious"));
  }
});
```

Comment: And cache the ID too

Comment: using $(this) returns the same result. It does not solve the problem. $(this) is referring to the same Select object.

Comment: @ShahriarFiroz Edited

Comment: @Omid Nikrah, thanks for editing. Yes this also works. The main thing I was missing in my code was, I was not using the event handler methods. Which basically did the deal.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the events to the function and can get the target element ID

```
select = $(".image").on("click", function(e) {
    console.log(e.target.id);
    if (e.target.id==="ObiWan"){
        $("#player").append($("#ObiWan"));
        $("#enemies").append($("#Luke"));
        $("#enemies").append($("#Sidious"));
        $("#enemies").append($("#Maul"));
    } else if (e.target.id==="Luke"){
        $("#player").append($("#Luke"));
        $("#enemies").append($("#ObiWan"));
        $("#enemies").append($("#Sidious"));
        $("#enemies").append($("#Maul"));
    } else if (e.target.id==="Sidious"){
        $("#player").append($("#Sidious"));
        $("#enemies").append($("#ObiWan"));
        $("#enemies").append($("#Luke"));
        $("#enemies").append($("#Maul"));
    } else if (e.target.id==="Maul"){
        $("#player").append($("#Maul"));
        $("#enemies").append($("#ObiWan"));
        $("#enemies").append($("#Luke"));
        $("#enemies").append($("#Sidious"));
    }
});
```